# Angular dynamic form change a child component value, and the other child component value also changed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have implemented a dynamic angular form app, which uses also child component, now I have a problem, If I change the value e.g input field, which is in a child component, and the other input field, which is created dynamically also from this child component, also changed.

now I show your my code

parent component

```
 <div
              *ngFor="let contact of form.get('contacts').controls; let contactIndex = index">
              <div [formGroupName]="contactIndex">
<div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
                  <div class="parameterLabel step">contact</div>
                  <modification-dropdown
                  [group]="contact"
                  name="cType"
                  [enumValues]="enumValues"
                  ></modification-dropdown>
                </div>
```

and child component

```
<label [formGroup]="group">
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <select class="parameterInputSelect" [formControlName]="name">
      <option *ngFor="let value of enumValues" [value]="value">
        {{value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</label>
```

and child component ts file

```
export class ModificationDropdownComponent{
  @Input() group: FormGroup;
  @Input() enumValues: string[];
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

the problem is, if I change a dropdown box and the other dropdown box also changed.

any solutions?

Comment: try  name="cType_{{contactIndex}}"

Comment: Hi Akhil I got this error Cannot find control with name: 'cType_0'

Comment: Can you change `[group]="contact"` to `[group]="contactof"`

Comment: no, that is right